# Dicompose LinSVM model into binary classifiers

Tags: classification, svm, libsvm

I have a multi-class .model trained with LibSVM. Is there a way to decompose this model into different binary .model?, For example if I have a .model trained for n classes, I would like to have (n-1)/2 binary classifiers separated, because as far as I know LibSVM train one vs one in order to obtain the multi-class classifier.

Comment: you can train n times binary models to achieve an equivalent one-vs-all classifier. After training you just predict the class with the highest probability

Answer (score 0):

In short : **yes**, it is possible

libsvm [model file is](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/faq.html#f402) (more or less) concatenation of n^2 submodels:

> In the model file, after parameters and other informations such as
>   labels , each line represents a support vector. Support vectors are
>   listed in the order of "labels" shown earlier. (i.e., those from the
>   first class in the "labels" list are grouped first, and so on.) If k
>   is the total number of classes, in front of a support vector in class
>   j, there are k-1 coefficients y*alpha where alpha are dual solution of
>   the following two class problems:  1 vs j, 2 vs j, ..., j-1 vs j, j vs
>   j+1, j vs j+2, ..., j vs k  and y=1 in first j-1 coefficients, y=-1 in
>   the remaining k-j coefficients. For example, if there are 4 classes,
>   the file looks like:
>
> ```
> +-+-+--------------------+
> |1|1|                    |
> |v|v|  SVs from class 1  |
> |2|3|                    |
> +-+-+--------------------+
> |1|2|                    |
> |v|v|  SVs from class 2  |
> |2|3|                    |
> +-+-+--------------------+
> |1|2|                    |
> |v|v|  SVs from class 3  |
> |3|3|                    |
> +-+-+--------------------+
> ```

So you can convert it (by hand!) into separate models and use each independently (or concatenate back to have a model with subset of classes).